# JPEG and PNG Library Use in PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm relatively new to development and I've been attempting to setup an application I'm building in Django (on Windows 7, 64 bit) to accept image uploads via ImageField. I initially installed PIL, but found that I needed JPEG and PNG libraries first. So I uninstalled PIL using "pip uninstall pil" and setup the libraries at C:\zlib-1.2.7\zlib.lib and C:\jpeg-8d\libjpeg.lib. Afterwards, I went into the setup.py in PIL and changed the following:

```
    JPEG_ROOT = "C:/jpeg-8d"
    ZLIB_ROOT = "C:/zlib-1.2.7"
```

I then install via:

```
    pip install C:\Imaging-1.1.7\
```

I got the following at the end of the install, which suggests there's JPEG and PNG support:

```
Installing collected packages: PIL
Running setup.py install for PIL
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package nam
es in setup.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      win32 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32)
              [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available (Tcl/Tk 8.5 libraries needed)
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
Successfully installed PIL
Cleaning up...
```

However, I got following when testing with selftest.py, which suggests no support:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python C:\Imaging-1.1.7\selftest.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from C:\Users\ayan\Desktop\Imaging-1.1.7\PIL
Binary modules loaded from C:\Python26_x86\lib\site-packages\PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** PIL CORE support not installed
*** TKINTER support not installed
*** JPEG support not installed
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also tried to work with a JPEG and got following IOError:

```
C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>> import os, sys
>>> import Image
>>> img = Image.open(Desert.jpg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Desert' is not defined
>>> img = Image.open("Desert.jpg")
>>> img.save("Desert_test.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26_x86\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1406, in save
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python26_x86\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 189, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "C:\Python26_x86\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 385, in _getdecode
r
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

This is somewhat similar to what was reported at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543581/pil-installation-run-issue; however, it appears that in this case, JPEGs actually aren't working. A similar problem is observed with PNGs.

It's not clear to me where in the process I've made a mistake, so any comments would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if additional information is required, I'll endeavor to do by best to provide it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved something similar but just for png support. I believe you can do the same for jpeg support as well.

First I would recommend using Pillow, a fork of PIL.
The solution I used is to manually compile on my machine (win7 64 bit) the zlib library.
And then manualy compiling the Pillow Package. I edited the Setup.py like you did to point at a directory where I put the zlib I just compiled.

I would suggest you manually compile the jpeg lib as well, and the zlib and then compile Pillow again. Make sure to uninstall previous versions of PIL/Pillow before doing it.

The link for my detailed answer of how to do it with zlib is:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190972/2501083

Hope this helps